# Mvvmcross nuget package not installing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin, mono, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I am trying to install the MvvmCross nuget package into a PCL but am having no luck.  I am trying to sift through the noise but everything I try does not seem to work.

I have the PCL profiles setup as per: http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/my-current-pcl-setup-in-visual-studio.html (and a number of existing stackoverflow pages)

I am trying to install:

MvvmCross.HotTuna.StartPack Version: 3.0.10

Using Package Manager Version 2.7.40808.167

But this is the error I get:

> Package Manager Console Host Version 2.7.40808.167
>
> Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.
>
> PM> install-package MvvmCross
>   Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack (≥ 3.0.10)'.
>   Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries (≥ 3.0.10)'.
>   Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore (≥ 3.0.10)'.
>   Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport (≥ 3.0.10)'.
>   Installing 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.10'.
>   Successfully installed 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.10'.
>   Installing 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore 3.0.10'.
>   Successfully installed 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore 3.0.10'.
>   Installing 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries 3.0.10'.
>   Successfully installed 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries 3.0.10'.
>   Installing 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack 3.0.10'.
>   Successfully installed 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack 3.0.10'.
>   Installing 'MvvmCross 3.0.10'.
>   Successfully installed 'MvvmCross 3.0.10'.
>   Adding 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.10' to PortableClassLibrary4.
>   Uninstalling 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.10'.
>   Successfully uninstalled 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.10'.
>   Install failed. Rolling back...
>   install-package : Could not install package 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.10'. You are trying to > install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+MonoAndroid16+MonoTouch10+sl40+wp71+win', but the package does not contain any assembly 
>   references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + install-package MvvmCross
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Any suggestions??

Comment: MonoTouch10 looks wrong to me - mine say MonoTouch40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to tweak the profiles anymore. Go to your profiles folder where you have put those xml files and delete the custom files.

You will see that you won't be able to create references to PCLs in droid or iOS projects using VS normal methods, but fear not. The new way to do it is by editing the csproj file in order to manually add the needed references.

You will be able to see the warning symbol into the references pseudo-folder in your vs project but it will work flawlessly.

Now try to install the nuget package. It should work. At least is working for me.

Please, watch this great video tutorial from @CheeseBaron if you want to know more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Q5kcW1rhB8

Cheers!

[@Newton_W](http://twitter.com/@Newton_W)

Comment: Thanks @Newton_W I was able to get that to work but was hoping to avoid this type of hack.  I am still trying to get it to work as Stuart Lodge demoed in the n+0 video.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with MvvmCross Nuget package. Once I upgraded and installed the latest version of Nuget in VS studio. This problem resolved for me. You may give it a try.